# Machine Learning: How to regularize output and force them to be away from 0?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, regularized

I am training a deep CNN model in Tensorflow and trying to maximize the pearson correlation between the `true labels` and `predictions`. For example, for true labels `y_true = [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0]`, I'd like to predict something like `y_pred = [0.9, 1.8, 3.0, 4.1]`, because this gives high pearson correlation.

However, my predictions are all highly closed to 0, something like `y_pred = [0.0001,0.0002, 0.0003, 0.0004]`. Although in this case the pearson correlation is high, the model is numerically unstable when calculating the pearson loss (e.g. NaN error was thrown).

Hence, I am wondering what I can do to enforce the output to have larger value so that is it not close to 0? Maybe some sort of regularizer on the output can scale it up?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you might try to model your problem as a regression one. Define as your loss as

```
(true_labels - predictions)^2
```

Since you will explicitly minimize the squared difference between labels and predictions, they will be highly correlated as well. You can retain your original loss for the Pearson correlation and add this as a regularizer in order to keep the predictions close to the true labels as well. Something like:

```
pearson_Loss + lambda * (true_labels - predictions)^2
```

You can find the optimal strength for your regularizer by fine tuning "lambda", via cross validation with grid search or randomized search.

Comment: Thank you! Can I also use [`tf.keras.layers.ActivityRegularization`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/ActivityRegularization) to regularize output? I tried but it has no effect...

Comment: As far as I know activity regularizers apply l2 or l1 norm loss to the network outputs. If you apply l2 activity regularizer directly to outputs, it will pull them towards zero; l1 activity regularizer tends to pull some of the outputs very quickly to zero and introduces sparsity. If you apply l2 activity regularizer to (true_labels-predictions) theoretically it should do the job. But I don't know if it would correctly backprop gradients through predictions, this should be tested.